# strsplit char into columns with column names

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a character string such as:

```
char = c("3 habs.", "2 baños", "102 m²", "4ª Planta")
```

I would like to split this into columns with the expected output:

```
habs baños m²   Planta
  3    2   102   4^a
```

I have the following:

```
char %>% 
  strsplit(" ") %>% 
  bind_cols()
```

Which gives:

```
New names:
• `` -> `...1`
• `` -> `...2`
• `` -> `...3`
• `` -> `...4`
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  ...1  ...2  ...3  ...4  
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 3     2     102   4ª    
2 habs. baños m²    Planta
```

Which is not exactly what I want, I would like row 2 to be the column names (I also don't want to use the `janitor::row_to_names()` function to do this - I would like to perhaps rename the lists first, then `bind_cols()`/`bind_rows()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Base R:

```
as.data.frame(t(sapply(strsplit(char, ' '), \(x)setNames(x[1], x[2]))))
  habs. baños  m² Planta
1     3     2 102     4ª
```

or even:

```
read.dcf(textConnection(sub("(\\S+) (\\S+)", '\\2:\\1', char)), all = TRUE)

  habs. baños  m² Planta
1     3     2 102     4ª
```

in tidyverse:

```
  str_split(char, ' ')%>%transpose()%>%invoke(set_names, .)%>%as_tibble()

# A tibble: 1 x 4
  habs. baños m²    Planta
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1 3     2     102   4ª
```

Answer (score 1):

Following your `strsplit` approach further.

```
strsplit(char, ' ') |>
  {\(.) as.data.frame(setNames(lapply(., `[`, 1), lapply(., `[`, 2)))}()
#   habs. baños  m. Planta
# 1     3     2 102     4ª
```